# Where is skype profile location path in windows 10 (Pre Installed Skype Of Win 10)

Tags: windows-10, skype

In windows 10 skype exists by default.
Where is the location of it's profiles in windows 10.
I searched many places for that and failed.
In regular installation of skype this path is like this :

> %appdata%\skype

But in windows 10 it is different:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\lync.exe
They did not change the name to skype yet.

Comment: Look in C:\Users\jusernameAppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Skype (for Desktop) . It should be similar to this.

Comment: There is no skype folder in this path - This path is for skype exe file installed by us, Not default skype of windows 10. This is why i asked this question here.

Comment: I am not sure then in this case.

Comment: Why not use system internals process explorer and see where the open handles are?

Comment: exe file runs from this path : `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SkypeApp_15.83.408.0_x86__kzf8qxf38zg5c\Skype`

Comment: So strange - I did n't see any profiles there.

Comment: @SilverLight - UWP applications have very specific folder access rules, I would be shocked if Skype would store a user's skype profile in that directory given that the installation directory would be used by all users on the device.

Comment: But in windows 7 i could delete profile files manually to reset skype. In pre installed skype of win 10 i do n't know after sign out is there any files on device related to that profile or not.

Comment: @SilverLight - Windows 7 cannot install the UWP Skype application.  What was true on Windows 7 isn't necessarily true with the UWP Skype application on Windows 10+.  I have a feeling that since the UWP application is connected to the Microsoft account, there isn't a profile directory for the UWP application.  Everything about your Skype profile is stored in the cloud with the current version.  In other words, since everything about Skype is in the cloud (messages, profile pictures, etc) there isn't a need for a local profile on the device.  *There is a link to switch accounts.*

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the clarification my friend. Please put your comment as answer.

Comment: I am not confident enough in my assumption to submit an answer